# How do i change any variables inside of a enum element?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, enums

This is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
     
public class Item
{
    public Inventory inventory;
    public enum ItemType
    {
        Blocks,
        Potions,
        Weapons,
    }

    public ItemType itemType
    public bool stackable;
     
}
```

and what I am trying to do is to change only the enum ItemType `Blocks` to stackable so that I can just use the add the item to the list, and if the item is blocked, it will be set to stackable by default.

how can I achieve this?

I tried `ItemTypes.Blocks.stackable = true;` But it won't work.

Comment: In your question - what is 'ItemTypes'? I see an 'itemType' field, but not 'ItemTypes'. Also, an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) is an immutable set of named numbers, you can't change the value of an enum as you seem to be trying. I think you need to add more detail to this question and provide lean code which replicates your use case as it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You've stated your question in a slightly confusing way. I think you want to set a value for `stackable` based on the value of `itemType` (the field), right?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes so let's say if the itemType is Blocks, then stackable will be true, and for other itemType like Potions and Weapons , the stackable bool will be false.

Comment: SO is not a forum.  Please don’t put _”(SOLVED)”_ in titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite poorly-worded so it is rather confusing. I'm going to make my best guess as to what you mean and recommend based on that. Firstly, get the `enum` out of the class. Nesting types is generally not a good idea.

```cs
 public enum ItemType
 {
     Blocks,
     Potions,
     Weapons
 }
```

Next, use properties to expose public data rather than fields. You can then provide additional implementation details:

```cs
 public class Item
 {
     public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
     public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
     public bool IsStackable => ItemType == ItemType.Blocks;
 }
```

The `IsStackable` property is read-only and its value is generated on the fly based on the value of the `ItemType` property.

Comment: Thanks so much this actually worked, but can u explain what the => function does?

Comment: @Dvereum It makes IsStackable a computed get-only in this case.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1:

Use an extension method to determine what is stackable.

```
public class Item
{
    public Inventory inventory;
    public enum ItemType
    {
        Blocks,
        Potions,
        Weapons,
    }

    public ItemType itemType; // Defaults to Blocks
}

public static class ItemTypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsStackable(this Item.ItemType type)
    {
        return type == Item.ItemType.Blocks;
    }
}
```

##### Usage

```
var item = new Item();
bool isStackable = item.itemType.IsStackable(); // true

item.itemType = Item.ItemType.Potions;
bool isStackable = item.itemType.IsStackable(); // false
```

### Option 2:

When you declare an enum value, it automatically uses the default element as the value. For any enum, that is the one that has the value 0. If you don't give them values (as in this case), the compiler will assign the first element with value 0. Therefore, the way you have constructed the enum `ItemTypes.Blocks` is the default value. You can rely on this default when your `Item` object is constructed.

```
public class Item
{
    public Inventory inventory;
    public enum ItemType
    {
        Blocks,
        Potions,
        Weapons,
    }

    public ItemType itemType; // Defaults to Blocks
    public bool stackable = true; // Set default explicitly (which matches up with blocks)
}
```

However, if you want the boolean value to stay in sync with your enum value, you either need to set them at the same time or create a method on the Item class to set them both together.

Comment: Of course, your method is not easy to design game elements. This may not be the case for applications, but there are better solutions for games such as struct. [IN MY OPINION]

Comment: @KiynL - Maybe you misunderstood the question, or maybe I did. But I don't think he meant he wanted to provide a way to set multiple types at the same time.

Comment: You got it right. But as it turns out, he basically wants to be able to freely change the properties of an item in the `rpg` game. For this purpose, a way independent of the extention class as well as freer accesses can be `struct`.

Comment: @KiynL - Actually, I like John's answer better than these. Much like the extension method,  there is no allocation for `IsStackable`, but it all happens inside the `Item` class. He also goes into C# coding conventions, which points beginners in the right direction.